# Cannot connect to Playstaion Network on Linux laptop

Tags: networking

Cannot connect to PlayStation Network on Linux laptop any more -

> Error A connection to the server could not be established.(18.11681160.1695034653.11d6fdbf)

Tried several Browsers / networks / vpn, all give the same error. However running a windows 10 VM works.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? How exactly do you connect to "PlayStation network"?

Comment: Maybe stupid question from me which  browser did you use in Windows?

Comment: PS Check also your addons in Linux Browser

Comment: I have used , Chrome, firefox, opera and librawolf. Disab;ed all add ons. I am using kde neon which is fully upto date. I am connecting via orange fibre. On the VM hosted on my Linux pc I use chrome - which is synced to my google account and so should be identical to my linux chrome.

Comment: Also not in ubuntu nor debian.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it; but only with the firefox-nightly build repo.

I found [bugreport](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1863300%20)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
```

refreshing

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install firefox-trunk
```

Start it with

```
firefox-trunk -P
```

so you can create a new profile.

[image: hello PSN]

Comment: thanks, A good solution to an odd problem

Comment: Saying thanks Here is to Accept the working answer 